# Web application input type file is not working in WebView

Tags: javascript, c#, html, web-applications, webview

I am trying to run my web application in web view (WebView2). There is a file selection tag (Input type = file) in my web application page and everything works fine when I run my web application normally. But, when I run web application in web view and click on input for selecting files, nothing happens. A file selection dialog must appear in web view but it is not appearing. I tried to find reason behind it but did not find anything.

Comment: Your app doesn't have permissions to use the file system?

Comment: @Teemu how can I give permission?

Comment: You don't, the user will if they wish.

Comment: @Teemu but for testing webView, I need to check it. Can you please tell me

Comment: How can we reproduce this issue so we can further help you?